# match first digits before # symbol

Tags: c#, regex

How to match all first digits before # in this line

```
26909578#Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi#356028416#2012-10-24 09:06#0#http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html#[URL=http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html]http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html[/URL]#<a href="http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html">http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html</a>#http://bitshare.com/?f=dvk9o1oz#http://bitshare.com/delete/dvk9o1oz/4511e6f3612961f961a761adcb7e40a0/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html
```

Im trying to get this number 26909578
My try

```
   string text = @"26909578#Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi#356028416#2012-10-24 09:06#0#http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html#[URL=http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html]http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html[/URL]#<a href=""http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html"">http://bitshare.com/files/dvk9o1oz/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html</a>#http://bitshare.com/?f=dvk9o1oz#http://bitshare.com/delete/dvk9o1oz/4511e6f3612961f961a761adcb7e40a0/Sbrntrl_7x06-lilla.avi.html";

        MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(text, @"(.+?)#", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

but then its outputs all text

Comment: try \d instead of . because it represents all characters, and \d only numeric digits. [Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) you have a cheat sheet where you can find its meaning

Comment: then i get four outputs. How to get only first ?

Comment: @dovydasjuraska `var firstMatch = m1[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it explicit that it has to start at the beginning of the string:

```
@"^(.+?)#"
```

Alternatively, if you know that this will always be a number, restrict the possible characters to digits:

```
@"^\d+"
```

Alternatively use the function `Match` instead of `Matches`. `Matches` explicitly says, "give me all the matches", while `Match` will only return the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Or, in a trivial case like this, you might also consider a non-RegEx approach. The `IndexOf()` method will locate the '#' and you could easily strip off what came before.

I even wrote a `sscanf()` replacement for C#, which you can see in my article [A sscanf() Replacement for .NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net).

Comment: Good one, it's seems much easier than with regex. gonna definitely try this out. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to/dont like to use regex, use a string builder and just loop until you hit the #.

so like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string yourdata = "yourdata";
int i = 0;
while(yourdata[i]!='#')
{
   sb.Append(yourdata[i]);
   i++;
}

//when you get to that # your stringbuilder will have the number you want in it so return it with .toString();

string answer = sb.toString();
```

Comment: and if you need to convert that number to an actual integer to play with for some reason or another, you can use the Convert() built in functions on it.

Answer (score 1):

The entire string (except the final url) is composed of segments that can be matched by `(.+?)#`, so you will get several matches. Retrieve only the first match from the collection returned by matching `.+?(?=#)`